# Why does rails credentials access using [ ] not mirror access via `send`

Tags: ruby

Trying to understand why I can access the credentials with string and symbol with send, but not with []

```rb
Rails.application.credentials.send 'production'
# {:one => {:two => {:three => 'yay!}}}
Rails.application.credentials.send :production
# {:one => {:two => {:three => 'yay!}}}
Rails.application.credentials['production']
# nil
Rails.application.credentials[:production]
# {:one => {:two => {:three => 'yay!}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior can be explained by looking at the source code of Ruby on Rails.

`Rails.application.credentials` returns an instance of [`EncryptedConfiguration`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb). There you find this line:

```
delegate :[], :fetch, to: :config
```

The first one tells that calls to `fetch` or `[]` are delegated to the `config` method. That method looks like this:

```
def config
  @config ||= deserialize(read).deep_symbolize_keys
end
```

Because it symbolizes the keys of the read credentials hash, you can only access its keys with symbols, not with strings.

But using `send` works differently. When using `send` Ruby doesn't care if the method name argument is a string or a symbol. It just calls that method name on the instance.

But because the structure of the credentials hash is dynamic, the called `prodcution` method does not exist. This is when this line from the source code comes into play:

```
delegate_missing_to :options
```

It tells delegating all calls to missing methods to the `options` method. And that method looks like this:

```
def options
  @options ||= ActiveSupport::InheritableOptions.new(deep_transform(config))
end
```

[`InheritableOptions`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/lib/active_support/ordered_options.rb#L83) translates a hash into an object that allows receiving value from the hash by calling methods instead of using hash getter methods.

That means the short answer to your question is: Both versions are implemented totally different, accept different arguments, and therefore behave differently.

Comment: I'm getting an instance of `ActiveSupport::EncryptedConfiguration` (Rails 7.0.2). But otherwise the behavior and explaination is the same.

Comment: @max You are right. The link was correct, but the link title was incorrect. I fixed my answer.